# how to check focus on elements and windows?

Tags: javascript

I want to find which element is on focus. Also, when a user opens multiple windows/tab, i'd like to know which window/tab is on the focus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In plain JavaScript (i.e. without any frameworks like jQuery, MooTools, etc.):

```
var focusedElement;

document.addEventListener("focus", function(e) {
    focusedElement = e.target;
}, true);

document.addEventListener("blur", function(e) {
    focusedElement = null;
}, true);
```

Basically, whenever an element gains focus, we save that element to a variable, and when the element loses focus, we reset the variable.

In HTML 5, there's a specific attribute for accessing the currently focused element:

```
var focusedElement = document.activeElement;
```

Comment: just be aware that as the user clicks around in the document text, (not <input> elements) the focus handler will be called with e.target set to the document on each click, with no intervening blur handler call.

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery, you can use this to find focus:

```
$("body").bind("onfocus", function (e) {
  alert("focus: " + e.target); // e.target is the element with focus
});
```

You need only one handler using [event delegation](http://www.sitepoint.com/blogs/2008/07/23/javascript-event-delegation-is-easier-than-you-think/) - the event percolates up the DOM tree until it is handled, so you can make do with one handler for the whole document.

See jQuery documentation for their [event object](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/jQuery.Event) and [event functions](http://docs.jquery.com/Events), it makes it much simpler to do this in a cross-browser fashion.

Multiple browser windows or tabs is not accessible from Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a **[tip](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=68288)**. Anyway, you have to add event handler for each input element on a page. Only alternative is IE-only: `document.activeElement`