# Determine whether webpage has foreground window focus/is active tab?

Tags: javascript, html, focus

I'd like to be able to mute activity of my app if I can detect that the page is no longer focused. For instance, if the page is in a background tab or another app has focus, I'd like to disable a constantly polling script or switch modal notifications to the new HTML5 notifications API.

Is there any way to get this with JS, and if so, which browsers are supported?

PS - I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720456/how-to-check-focus-on-elements-and-windows/1720810#1720810), but don't know if it would work for what I'm looking to do. Anybody have any insight?

Comment: There is a new API called Page Visibility API. See [How to know a browser is minimized in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64229054/11667949)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can listen for the `blur` event on your `window`, then for when the user comes back, you can use the `focus` event:

Here's an example in jQuery:

```
$(window).blur(disableStuff).focus(enableStuff);
```

Or in pure JavaScript:

```
window.onblur = disableStuff;
window.onfocus = enableStuff;
```

Comment: Awesome, I'll check this out tomorrow!