# Is it possible to tell if a user has my page minimized or the inactive tab?

Tags: javascript, tabs

I am messing around with some web pages and was wondering if it is possible to tell if my page is not the active page on a web browser. I am looking to tell if my page is minimized or is not the current tab. I am not asking about a particular language, but more just wondering if it is possible to get this sort of information.

Comment: There is a new API called Page Visibility API. See [How to know a browser is minimized in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64229054/11667949)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, its totally possible, with javascript.

See these answers:

[Determine whether webpage has foreground window focus/is active tab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3268298/determine-whether-webpage-has-foreground-window-focus-is-active-tab)

[How to tell if browser/tab is active](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760250/how-to-tell-if-browser-tab-is-active)

[Is there a way to detect if a browser window is not currently active?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060008/is-there-a-way-to-detect-if-a-browser-window-is-not-currently-active)

Comment: @ian Thank you sir. This is exactly what I was looking for. I was pretty sure there would be something like this in javascript, but I was not too familiar with it, so I was not where to look.

Comment: Haha I will. I plan no harm with this, just trying to see what all is possible. Could do some neat stuff with this I think.

Comment: All of these solutions use the ``blur`` event, which will fire if the user just focuses the address line, even if the page remains visible. Tested without jQuery on Seamonkey 2.0.14

Answer (score 0):

You can check it with Javascript and then send a message to the server. But since the user can alter/disable the script you can never know for sure.