# How can i stop html5 audio when ios safari (tab) goes to background?

Tags: javascript, ios, html, audio, safari

i have a html5 audio playing on a website and i want it to stop as soon as the browser tab or the browser is hidden. i have a function that checks for requestAnimationFrames BUT as .pause() now can only be triggered after a click event on ios, this does not work. is there any way of stopping the audio on (current) ios?

Comment: Is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3268298/ what you want?

Comment: no as i said, i can detect being in backround, but calling .pause() will do nothing there because it doesn't come from a click/touchstart event

Comment: Yes it does. You can pause at any time. Only play/load needs user interaction.